# queue.put(), what item to put in put()?

Tags: python, thread-safety, queue

The queue module has an example code:
(https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue):

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

q.join()
```

What I don't understand is, what is the source() function, and what are the 'items'?

I have a class that does something like this:

```
class do_stuff():
    def do_some_thing_1():
          #do something 1

    def do_some_thing_2():
          #do something 2

    def do_some_thing_3():
          #do something 3

    def do_them_all():
          self.do_some_thing_1()
          self.do_some_thing_2()
          self.do_some_thing_3()
```

and in my GUI script, I call the class's do_them_all():

```
  some_button(command = get_it_done)

  def get_it_done():
      get_done = do_stuff()
      get_done.do_them_all()
```

and each do_thing function depend on the previous function to be complete first. but in the final class implantation, do_some_thing_3 may be triggered before do_some_thing_2 completes, or do_some_thing_2 is triggered before do_some_thing_1 completes.

How do I implement this queue? 
do I modify do_them_all():

```
def do_them_all():
    queue.put(do_some_thing_1)
    queue.put(do_some_thing_2)
    queue.put(do_some_thing_3)

    queue.join()
```

Comment: `source()` is a function that returns a list of items, or an iterator over them.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do that with a simple:

```
queue.put(do_some_thing_1)
queue.put(do_some_thing_2)
queue.put(do_some_thing_3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
queue.put(do_stuff.do_some_thing_1)
queue.put(do_stuff.do_some_thing_2)
queue.put(do_stuff.do_some_thing_3)
```

I think you can try it:

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q.put(do_stuff.do_some_thing_1)
q.put(do_stuff.do_some_thing_2)
q.put(do_stuff.do_some_thing_3)

for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()


q.join()
```